# Angular - Child to parent communication when child is content projected

Tags: angular

I am in the middle of a project building a Header component in Angular which has 2 levels of navigation. The basic component structure is as follows:

```html
<b-header>
  <b-header-nav>
    <b-header-nav-item>
      <button b-header-link>Primary 1<button>
    </b-header-nav-item>
    <b-header-nav-item>
      <button b-header-link>Primary 2<button>
    </b-header-nav-item>
    <b-header-nav-item>
      <button b-header-link>Primary 3<button>
    </b-header-nav-item>
  </b-header-nav>
</b-header>
```

When the user clicks on one of the `b-header-link` buttons I would like to toggle CSS active state classes on both the button itself and its parent - `b-header-nav-item`. I have researched child to parent communication in Angular online but most examples show the use of Output and Event Emitters which I'd ideally not like to use as this work is part of a component library where the inner workings of a component should not really be exposed to the end user. Also as shown the child in this case is added via content projection `ng-content` in `b-header-nav-item`. I've created a Stackblitz to demo a more featured example of the code (although still simplified compared to the real one).

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g8vdml?file=src/app/header/header-link/header-link.component.ts

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Ng-Content, you can handle all the logic in one component. I therefore suggest you try using an array containing all of your buttons data (is active, title, href), then using ngfor to render it.

1 Define NavButton interface :

```
export interface NavButton {
       isActive: boolean;
       name: string;
       href: string;
       subElems: NavButton[];
   }
```

2 Create buttons list and function to toggle the btn's 'active' parameter

```
navItems: NavButton[] = [{isActive: false, name: 'btn1', href: '', subElems: []}, {isActive: false, name: 'btn2', href: '', subElems: [{isActive: false, name: 'subBtn 2.1', href: '', subElems: []}]}, {isActive: false, name: 'btn3', href: '', subElems: []}, ];
  
  changeState = (navBtn: NavButton) => {
    navBtn.isActive = !navBtn.isActive;
  }
```

3 Render nav buttons and subButtons like so :

```
<b-header>
  <b-header-nav>
    navItemMap
    <b-header-nav-item *ngFor="let currBtn of navItems; let i = index">
      <button b-header-link (click)="changeState(currBtn)">
        {{currBtn.name}} (number {{ i }})
      </button>

      <b-header-subnav *ngIf="currBtn.subElems.length > 0">
      <b-header-subnav-item *ngFor="let subNavBtn of currBtn.subElems; let i2 = index;">
        <a [href]="subNavBtn.href" (click)="changeState(subNavBtn)">{{subNavBtn.name}} (number {{ i2 }})</a>
      </b-header-subnav-item>
    </b-header-subnav>
    </b-header-nav-item>
  </b-header-nav>
</b-header>
```

4 Everything is set up, just add style binding to HTML, for example if you want the "b-header-nav-item" to get a specific CSS class as well as the "b-header-link" once toggled :

```
 <b-header-nav-item *ngFor="....." [class.active]="currBtn.isActive">
          <button b-header-link (click)="...." [class.active]="currBtn.isActive"></button>
       
[...]

        </b-header-nav-item>
```

*Note: Here, I've hidden the non-style related logic for visibility*

Cheers

Comment: I could go down this route but I discussed how the component(s) should be instantiated and the design of the API with my team. We voted in favour of the menu's structure being defined in the template - so if you need 4 links in your menu you put those in your application rather than passing in an object with 4 items in it. If its not possible to solve the problem in my original post without approaching it this way then we would have to revisit that decision however.

Comment: Why do you want to add the nav logic inside the HTML file instead of the TS one ? Also I'm pretty sure that the *ngFor instanciates components.

Comment: What I mean is if someone using the component wants a Header with 4 clickable buttons they define those in the HTML file of their application. So sub-components like header-nav are fairly basic and contain ng-content to allow consumers to pass in either anchors or buttons if they wish.